# Log In To Facebook Via Web Services

Tags: facebook, authentication, service

I'd like to authenticate users on my site by providing an HTML form for them to for username and password, then submit that from the same page via web services to Facebook, e.g. api.facebook.com for auth. Is this possible? Don't want use Facebook JavaScript SDK or PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You can not auth a user using their username and password